# Что не так? was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Смущает меня в первую очередь то что рядом два очень похожих объявления, одно с ошибкой другое без.

```
ошибка: ‘ContactFaceElement’ was not declared in this scope
     QList<ContactFaceElement *> face;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ошибка: template argument 1 is invalid
     QList<ContactFaceElement *> face;
                               ^


#ifndef ORGANISATIONELEMENT_H
#define ORGANISATIONELEMENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <elementDB/contactfaceelement.h>
#include <elementDB/geoelement.h>
#include <QStringList>

class OrganisationElement : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit OrganisationElement(QObject *parent = 0);

  class element
  {
    QString name;
    QList<ContactFaceElement *> face; // ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ
    QList<GeoElement *> geo;
    QStringList sites;
    QStringList phone;
  };
  bool findOrganisation(OrganisationElement::element);
  bool findOrganisationFromEmail(QString);
  QList<OrganisationElement::element*> elements;

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // ORGANISATIONELEMENT_H
```

> !    два класса
>
> ```
> #ifndef CONTACTFACEELEMENT_H
> #define CONTACTFACEELEMENT_H
>
> #include <QObject>
> #include <elementDB/geoelement.h>
> #include <QDate>
> #include <QStringList>
> #include <elementDB/organisationelement.h>
>
> class ContactFaceElement : public QObject
> {
>   Q_OBJECT
> public:
>   explicit ContactFaceElement(QObject *parent = 0);
>
>   class element
>   {
>     QString name;
>     QString last_name;
>     QString patronymic;
>     QDate birthday;
>     GeoElement * geo;
>     QStringList phone;
>   };
>   bool findContactFace(ContactFaceElement::element);
>   bool findContactFaceFromEmail(QString);
>   QList<ContactFaceElement::element *> face;
>   QList <int> id_contact_face;
>   void readListIdContactFace_FromOrganisation(OrganisationElement*);
>
> signals:
>
> public slots:
>
> private:
>   void readListIdContactFace_Email(QString);
>   void addIdContactFace(int);
>
> };
>
> #endif // CONTACTFACEELEMENT_H
> #ifndef GEOELEMENT_H
> #define GEOELEMENT_H
>
> #include <QObject>
> #include <QStringList>
>
> class GeoElement : public QObject
> {
>   Q_OBJECT
> public:
>   explicit GeoElement(QObject *parent = 0);
>   class g
>   {
>     public:
>
>     QString city;
>     QString country;
>     QString region;
>     QString state;
>     int zip_code;
>     QString street;
>     int home;
>     QString home_word;
>     int box;
>     int box_word;
>     QString currency_code;
>     QString currency;
>     int id_countries;
>     int id_cities;
>     bool biggest_city;
>     int id_rayon;
>     QString rayon;
>   };
>
>   bool findGeo(GeoElement::g);
>   bool findGeoFromEmail(QString);
>   QList<GeoElement::g*> geos;
>   QList<int> id_geo;
>
>
> signals:
>
> public slots:
>
> private:
>   int idGeoInfoEmail(int);
>   int idGeoList(int);
>   void addGeosFromId(int);
> };
>
> #endif // GEOELEMENT_H
> ```

Comment: почему у вас `#include <elementDB/contactfaceelement.h>`, а не `#include "elementDB/contactfaceelement.h"`?

Comment: для единообразия кода, такой способ подключения работает тоже

Comment: в каком порядке подключены заголовочные файлы в файле .pro (HEADERS)?

Comment: elementDB/geoelement.h \
    elementDB/contactfaceelement.h \

Comment: а если сделать так? `elementDB/organisationelement.h \ elementDB/geoelement.h \  elementDB/contactfaceelement.h \ `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за того, что где-то `contactfaceelement.h` используется раньше, чем `organisationelement.h`. Из-за этого компилятор не находит декларацию класса `ContactFaceElement`

Используйте *predeclaration* в `organisationelement.h`

```
#ifndef ORGANISATIONELEMENT_H
#define ORGANISATIONELEMENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <elementDB/contactfaceelement.h>
#include <elementDB/geoelement.h>
#include <QStringList>

// Добавьте предварительное объявление класса
class ContactFaceElement;

class OrganisationElement : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  // Дальше ваш код
};
```

Но вам надо разобраться в порядке использования includ-ов в остальных хидерах

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, насколько использование predeclaration является костылём? Недавно прочитал что некоторые мои проблемы решаются именно подобным образом, и хотелось бы узнать, это костыль и всё же надо додумывать структуру проекта, или нормальная практика.

Comment: @Angus123 predeclaration - это обычная практика. Так, что не бойтесь ее использовать. Единственно, если у вас накопится очень много predeclaration, это тоже может привести к конфликтам. Вот тогда есть повод задуматься, о том, что что-то неладно в Датском королевстве.